# Refresh oauth token in R using rgoogle analytics

Tags: r, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to refresh oauth token in R using rgoogle analytics library in order to export data from Google Analytics. When I create new token and try to connect, everything works just fine. I am using the following code:

```
require(RGoogleAnalytics)
oauth_token<-Auth(client.id = "client_id", client.secret= "client_secret")    
save(oauth_token, file="oauth_token")
```

Problem occurs, when I try to refresh token by using:

```
ValidateToken(oauth_token)
```

I always get

> Error: Refresh token not available.

I already checked, whether the file is saved in current working directory, tried to rename file, move it to different directory and change accordingly current working directory, use absolute path in command, but nothing worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are `oauth_token$refresh` method exists?

Comment: @ArtemKlevtsov Thanks for your response. Could you please further explain your question, because I am not sure I understand you. Anyway, file should be saved in the right directory, validatetoken is valid function of rgoogle analytics and I also checked, whether oauth_token is correctly defined and it looks like it is.

Comment: After successful authorization try to call  `oauth_token$refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and after some tries, what worked was to call **init_credentials()** in the token object.

Doing that the login page re-launches and the **ValidateToken()** worked again

```
oauth_token$init_credentials()

ValidateToken(oauth_token)
```